# How to capture "@" and "#" key pressed - Silverlight Textbox Keyup Event

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I wrote below code for capturing "@" and "#" pressed or not. And working perfectly fine on Emulator and Samsung Focus. But when deploy to Nokia Lumia 800 and pressed "@" it wont resulted in Key.D2 and below code not working.

```
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.D2)
        {
            myAutocompleteBox.Text = "@";
            updateAutocompleteBox = true;
        }
        else if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.D3)
        {
            myAutocompleteBox.Text = "#";
            updateAutocompleteBox = true;
        }
        else if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Back)
        {
            if (myAutocompleteBox.Text != String.Empty && updateAutocompleteBox == true)
            {
                string autoCompleteText = myAutocompleteBox.Text;
                myAutocompleteBox.Text = autoCompleteText.Substring(0, autoCompleteText.Length - 1);
            }
        }
```

Please guide me how can i capture "@" and "#" key pressed on my textbox. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you show us any part of the code?

Answer (score 3):

I think the value of D2 or D3 depends on the keyboard layout in use. In the EN-US Layout SHIFT+2 is @ in DE-DE SHIFT+2 is doublequotes and D0 - D9 are variable based on the layout used. In your code you might have to take that into account when translating the key pressed to the String value.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

It's got all the Key Enumeration for Windows Phone 7, had a look but couldn't spot `@` or `#`.

What value is being returned for `e.Key`?

Comment: I checked that earlier but that not helped me :( as mentioned in snipped it returns me D2 and D3. Same key returned for numeric value 2 and 3 and also some other char like "'".

Comment: Changed the logic, now on keydown event checking which new character has been typed and based on that performing operations